# COPY in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm looking for the best way to copy a folder from a localhost to Docker container, then launch bash command inside the container?

I proceed as following instruction inside Dockerfile :

```
WORKDIR /workspace/
COPY /path_in_localhost /Project    
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", " cd /workspace/Project/ && make"]
```

the issue is when Docker come to the last instruction, it can find the folder, it's like the copy doesn't work?

```
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: /workspace/Project: No such file or directory
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: `/Project` ≠ `/workspace/Project/` Did you mean `COPY /path_in_localhost Project`?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to take advantage of WORKDIR you need to use relative path, thus specifying `Project` without the `/` as destination.